# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Serializable'

Tags: angular, angular5

I can't understand why it's not working, it used to, and can't find the mistake.

I a class:

```
//my-class.service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from './my-data.model';

@Injectable()
export class myClass implements Serializable<myData> {
}


//my-data.model:
export class myData {

  constructor(
     public data1: string,
  ){}
}
```

When compiling:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Serializable'.
```

What are I am missing?

maybe some dependence?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Serializable from somewhere. I can't find it in the Angular documentation. I assume then it is a third party library that needs to be added via npm for example.